# Linux: Advanced Grub Bootloader configuration?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub, bootloader, editing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Aesthetically editing grub.cfg](https://superuser.com/questions/111302/aesthetically-editing-grub-cfg)
>   [Make grub keep its default boot under kernel updates](https://superuser.com/questions/102692/make-grub-keep-its-default-boot-under-kernel-updates)

Hello,

I want to use the Grub bootloader to boot up my system with my triple boot.

Now, i want to configure grub on my Ubuntu OS. How can I? I want to do stuff like editing the startup entries, like you could do with EasyBCD for Windows. Startup-Manager in the Ubuntu softwarecentre doesn do this. Can anyone give me a recommendation?

Comment: duplicates: http://superuser.com/questions/111302/aesthetically-editing-grub-cfg and http://superuser.com/questions/102692/make-grub-keep-its-default-boot-under-kernel-updates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it done,

Threw terminal:

```
cp /boot/grub/grub.cfg /home/me/Desktop (edit the file on the desktop, save)
Add root password: sudo passwd root
su root
cp /home/me/Desktop/grub.cfg /boot/grub
```

Worked for me.

Comment: this works until you install a new kernel.  at which point *update-grub* is run and your special */boot/grub/grub.cfg* is overwritten.  see the duplicates for how to do it so that *grub.cfg* is auto-generated with your changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you enter the command:

> gksudo gedit /boot/grub/menu.lst

from the command line, it will let you edit the grub entries in a text editor. You don't specifically say you are looking for a GUI editor, but you could use Gnome System Tools which has a graphical editor as well.

Comment: on the new Grub 2 grub.cfg replaces menu.lst

Comment: Did you try sudo update-grub? If not look at this tutorial: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=8191211