# Linux/Ubuntu: Update grub?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, grub

When i want to update grub, with the command `update-grub` in terminal, it says the menu.lst file isnt there, which seems obvious, because it has a grub.cfg file. Why does it not want to work with the grub.cfg file?

Running Ubuntu 9.10 GNOME. (32 Bit)

Comment: Are you running grub or grub2 (1.9x)? If your 9.10 is an upgrade from an earlier release, by default it won't give you the new stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have it.

Just run the `update-grub`, just dont create the menu.lst file.

Then just restart and you should have it :)

Answer (score 0):

See [my answer](https://superuser.com/questions/92689/linux-advanced-grub-bootloader-configuration) for your other question. It may help.

Grub uses menu.lst, I haven't seen what the grub.cfg file is even used for.

Comment: the cfg file replaces menu.lst in the new Grub 2