# How to change the order of OS's on my boot screen on a dual boot setup?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, multi-boot

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Make grub keep its default boot under kernel updates](https://superuser.com/questions/102692/make-grub-keep-its-default-boot-under-kernel-updates)
>    [Aesthetically editing grub.cfg](https://superuser.com/questions/111302/aesthetically-editing-grub-cfg)

I'm running a dual boot configuration on my laptop using Ubuntu 10.04b and Windows 7 Home Premium.

Windows 7 was the original OS and I added a 'side by side' installation of Ubuntu. Ubuntu, however, shows up first on the list. I'd like to change this order and make Windows 7 first, followed by Ubunutu, then all of the recovery boots after that.

Any help on how this is done?

Comment: I'd give you +2 if I could for the fact that you have a Steelers avatar. :D

Comment: The question is not exactly the same, but the answer is.

Comment: It is a duplicate in that the end result is the same (as @heavyd mentions above). But the question is asked from the perspective of someone it seems doesn't even know that GRUB is at the center of the issue. So it seems more of a newbish question and I think the answers can be provided in that light as well. That's just my input.

Comment: Hah, thanks for the 'newbish' comment. But honestly, I'm not very familiar with boot managers.

Comment: @th3dude19 no offense intended by that. I do think that this is a bit of a simpler question in essence since it doesn't come out of the gate as a GRUB question. I think that will be a good addition to the answer seeking community.

Comment: And fwiw I still consider myself a newb...

Comment: @codeLes - no worries at all! We're all newbs at something. I like to consider myself pretty knowledgeable on many topics, but boot managers aren't one of them!

Answer (score 0):

I found [this thread](http://newyork.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1440635) with a quick Google search and a couple times they refer to *startupmanager*. I've never used it but Download Squad has a write up on it [here](http://www.downloadsquad.com/2008/10/10/ubuntu-tip-use-startup-manager-to-edit-your-boot-menu/).

> Startup Manager, or SUM provides an easier way to edit your GRUB menu. You can find SUM in the Synaptic package manager or by typing **sudo apt-get install startupmanager** into a terminal window.
>
> Once it's installed, you can access Startup Manager from the System -> Administration menu. The utility lets you change the default operating system, adjust the screen resolution of the GRUB menu, and even alter the background and text colors. You can adjust the countdown timer, set a password, or alter a number of other settings. And there's fairly little risk of messing up your boot menu beyond all repair.

Prior to the current version of grub it was quite simple to update a config file and I used to do that. You can still update it in a similar way but it is a [bit more convoluted](https://superuser.com/questions/111302/aesthetically-editing-grub-cfg).

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: StartupManager basically sounds like it's tweaking the Grub variables in */etc/default/grub* (tho setting background/text colors might actually rewrite one of the */etc/grub.d* scripts).  i think i tried SUM once and it didn't work at all (as in, wouldn't even run).  i've always found the GUI configurators less fine-grained than i like so i prefer going directly to the config files.

Comment: @quackQ I agree in general. I've only ever updated the config files myself. After finding this tool I gave it a try at just setting the default OS to my Windows partition. Worked. Until I updated my Ubuntu and it no longer was set... had to go in again... strange behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to edit your grub.cfg file. [here](https://superuser.com/questions/111302/aesthetically-editing-grub-cfg) you'll find a good answer for this question.

P.S.: I don't really know about this but I guess this could be evaluated as duplicate.

Comment: It is almost a duplicate, but the essence of this question is almost independent of editing grub manually. I suppose that could also be found out by reading down the answers of the other questions, but it might be a bit misleading to someone who just wants to edit the ordering/default OS without prior knowledge of the technologies involved.